# Jssor Slider not showing

Tags: jquery, html

I downloaded the free Jssor slider and tried putting it to my HTML site, when I test it through local it works just fine but when I test it in live site it doesn't show up.

### Here is the code for the Jssor:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title></title>
```

```
<!-- #region Jssor Slider Begin -->

<!-- Generated by Jssor Slider Maker Online. -->
<!-- This demo works with jquery library -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.mini.js"></script>
<!-- use jssor.slider.debug.js instead for debug -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$SlideOut:true,$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$During:{$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,y:-0.3,$Cols:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:12},$Easing:{$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:-0.3,$Rows:2,$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Row:3},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,x:0.3,y:0.3,$Cols:2,$Rows:2,$During:{$Left:[0.3,0.7],$Top:[0.3,0.7]},$SlideOut:true,$ChessMode:{$Column:3,$Row:12},$Easing:{$Left:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Top:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:3,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$InCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2},
          {$Duration:1200,$Delay:20,$Clip:12,$SlideOut:true,$Assembly:260,$Easing:{$Clip:$Jease$.$OutCubic,$Opacity:$Jease$.$Linear},$Opacity:2}
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
          $AutoPlay: true,
          $SlideshowOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
            $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
            $TransitionsOrder: 1
          },
          $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
          },
          $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
            $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
            $Cols: 10,
            $SpacingX: 8,
            $SpacingY: 8,
            $Align: 360
          }
        };

        var jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var refSize = jssor_1_slider.$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (refSize) {
                refSize = Math.min(refSize, 800);
                jssor_1_slider.$ScaleWidth(refSize);
            }
            else {
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
            }
        }
        ScaleSlider();
        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>

<style>

    /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 05 css */
    /*
    .jssora05l                  (normal)
    .jssora05r                  (normal)
    .jssora05l:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora05r:hover            (normal mouseover)
    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn      (mousedown)
    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn      (mousedown)
    */
    .jssora05l, .jssora05r {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        /* size of arrow element */
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: url('img/a17.png') no-repeat;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jssora05l { background-position: -10px -40px; }
    .jssora05r { background-position: -70px -40px; }
    .jssora05l:hover { background-position: -130px -40px; }
    .jssora05r:hover { background-position: -190px -40px; }
    .jssora05l.jssora05ldn { background-position: -250px -40px; }
    .jssora05r.jssora05rdn { background-position: -310px -40px; }

    /* jssor slider thumbnail navigator skin 01 css */
    /*
    .jssort01 .p            (normal)
    .jssort01 .p:hover      (normal mouseover)
    .jssort01 .p.pav        (active)
    .jssort01 .p.pdn        (mousedown)
    */
    .jssort01 .p {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 72px;
        height: 72px;
    }

    .jssort01 .t {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: none;
    }

    .jssort01 .w {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .jssort01 .c {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 68px;
        height: 68px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
        box-sizing: content-box;
        background: url('img/t01.png') -800px -800px no-repeat;
        _background: none;
    }

    .jssort01 .pav .c {
        top: 2px;
        _top: 0px;
        left: 2px;
        _left: 0px;
        width: 68px;
        height: 68px;
        border: #000 0px solid;
        _border: #fff 2px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01 .p:hover .c {
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        border: #fff 1px solid;
        background-position: 50% 50%;
    }

    .jssort01 .p.pdn .c {
        background-position: 50% 50%;
        width: 68px;
        height: 68px;
        border: #000 2px solid;
    }

    * html .jssort01 .c, * html .jssort01 .pdn .c, * html .jssort01 .pav .c {
        /* ie quirks mode adjust */
        width /**/: 72px;
        height /**/: 72px;
    }

</style>


<div id="jssor_1" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 456px; overflow: hidden; visibility: hidden; background-color: #24262e;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div data-u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
        <div style="position:absolute;display:block;background:url('img/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
    </div>
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 800px; height: 356px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 1.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-01.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 2.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-02.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 3.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-03.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 4.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-04.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 5.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-05.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 6.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-06.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 7.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-07.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 8.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-08.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 9.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-09.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 10.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-10.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 11.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-11.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div data-p="144.50" style="display: none;">
            <img data-u="image" src="img/Picture 12.png" />
            <img data-u="thumb" src="img/thumb-12.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Thumbnail Navigator -->
    <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="jssort01" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:800px;height:100px;" data-autocenter="1">
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin Begin -->
        <div data-u="slides" style="cursor: default;">
            <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                <div class="w">
                    <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="c"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Thumbnail Item Skin End -->
    </div>
    <!-- Arrow Navigator -->
    <span data-u="arrowleft" class="jssora05l" style="top:158px;left:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
    <span data-u="arrowright" class="jssora05r" style="top:158px;right:8px;width:40px;height:40px;"></span>
    <a href="http://www.jssor.com" style="display:none">Jssor Slider</a>
</div>

<!-- #endregion Jssor Slider End -->
```

Comment: That's the problem, even though I inputted the jssor code, the slider doesnt show up. Try to right click and inspect element...

Answer (score 0):

Please upload 'jquery-1.9.1.min.js' and 'jssor.slider.mini.js' to your 'js' folder.